# Fitbit Graphical interface ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, software-sources

Fitbit snycs etc etc, I am just curious if anyone knows of software to go with it like windows has.

(There is no issue with it syncing w the USB adapter and uploading the info 2 their server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone knows of the software to go with it, and [anyone can be found here](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25906).

As you can see, this is a job for WINE.  If you take my advice, rather than install WINE, you will go to the [Ubuntu Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/software-center/) and install WineTricks.  This way you'll run into fewer problems in the future when you need to install anything that requires WINE.

Comment: I kinda figured you might have been thinking about that, but I remember the years I spent trying to make WINE work the hard way.  So much wasted effort trying to figure out what I was missing, putting together folders of bits of MS to try to make it work before discovering that winetricks would do it all for me.

Comment: Do i need 2 keep wine for winetricks or can I just remove wine n install winetricks?

Comment: Ironically had you tried to install winetricks with wine already installed, it would have instructed you to remove it first, so to answer your question first open the software center, then locate wine in it and select remove.  It will remove it adequately regardless of how you installed it.  Then while still in the software center, locate winetricks and install that.  Finally before exiting, unless your hard disk is nearing full, I recommend you install PlayOnLinux, which has certain undeniable benefits you may appreciate later.